# how to select records which has a column that has a later time?

Tags: mysql

I want to select records that has a column that has a later time in mysql.

for example i have this table :

```
Id | Content | Date
1  | lorem   | 2015/05/26
2  | lorem   | 2015/05/20
3  | lorem   | 2015/05/27
4  | lorem   | 2015/06/05
5  | lorem   | 2015/05/20
6  | lorem   | 2015/06/05
7  | lorem   | 2015/03/14
```

I want to select Id 4 and 6 because they are closer to now.

Comment: So you want entries with the latest date, right?

Comment: Yes I want the latest date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This I think will get you all the rows that contain the most recent date

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `Date` = (SELECT MAX(`Date`) FROM `table`);
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE Date_Field in 
    (SELECT date_field FROM table ORDER BY Date_Field desc LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP wants all rows with the latest date, judging by his required output suggestion. So nothing this simple will do the job

Comment: this error occurred #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 * FROM 'questions' ORDER BY 'question_time' DESC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 and my sql was SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM 'questions' ORDER BY 'question_time' DESC

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't understand it that way, but it seems you are probably right. I will modify accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Simply sort by date field in descending order.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

If you want to select number of records for instance 10 records then limit 10.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP wants all rows with the latest date, judging by his required output suggestion. So nothing this simple will do the job

Comment: You are right. I shouldn't limit. Thanks.

Comment: I want the most closest record to now

Comment: So you can add `WHERE Date <= CURDATE()`